# cygwin programming

Tags: java, windows, cygwin, compilation

how do you compile java progrmas in cygwin?

Comment: You should be more precise. Your question is very vague.

Answer (score 1):

With `javac`, as normal - alternatively using something like Ant which works under cygwin, with [some caveats](http://ant.apache.org/manual/platform.html).

The fact that you're asking the question suggests you've had problems - could you explain what you've tried and what went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Maven works also right out of the box. Cygwin & mintty combo rocks compared to windows cmd.

When running java-programs from cygwin you should remember that java-command is in windows, so it requires windows paths to jars. More info: http://www.inonit.com/cygwin/faq/.

Answer (score 0):

The same way as you would using a "normal" Windows shell.

Answer (score 0):

You can compile individual class files with the `javac` command.  If you have an existing project, it likely has a `build.xml`, `pom.xml`, or `Makefile`, in which case you need to run `ant`, `mvn`, or `make` respectively.